# Find cell in range then offset producing error VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to find a reservation# in a range. Then offset the active cell to the left. I have tried at least 3 different variations form online sources, but I cant get anything to work.

Here is what I have so far.

```
Dim FindString As String

    FindString = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I1").Value
With Worksheets(1).Range("H1:H7")
    Set C = .Find(FindString, LookIn:=xlValues)
    C.Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0,-1)
End With
```

Put simply the code uses the value of I1 and searches (H1:H7) then offsets one cell to the left, but I keep getting "Expected =" or "Syntax" errors.

Comment: Perhaps you are trying for `C.Offset(0,-1).Activate` or to ensure that the 'one cell to the left' is the only cell in the current selection `C.Offset(0,-1).Select`

Comment: Yes It worked! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
If not C is nothing then
    C.Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0,-1).Activate
Else
    'Some code for not found
End If
```